# How to proper inizialize a pointer to char array?

Tags: c++, sorting, char

i need some help for this sorting function. The aim of this function is to create an array of pointer to char to let the user fill it with some words an gets it back sorted with alphabetical order. This is part of the code:

```
void Sort(bool flag)
{
if(flag == false)
{
    //ordina stringhe
    int NumString = 0;

    cout<<"Number of strings: ";
    cin>>NumString; //!!
    char *Vector[NumString];

    for(int i=0;i<NumString;i++)
    {
        cout<<"Insert the "<<i<<" element: ";
        cin>>Vector[i];

        int Val = 0;
        char* swap;

        for(int i=0;i<NumString;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<NumString;j++)
            {
                Val = strcmp(Vector[i],Vector[j]);

                if(Val > 0)
                {
                   swap = Vector[i];
                   Vector[i]=Vector[j];
                   Vector[j]=swap;
                }
            }
        }

        for(int i=0;i<NumString;i++)
        {
            cout<<Vector[i];
            cout<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

And when i try to run it i get this error but i don't understand why.
This is the output of the program:

**Number of strings: 3
Insert the 0 element: abc
read from master failed
                       : Input/output error
RUN FAILED (exit value 1, total time: 7s)**

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char*`. With `char*` you have to allocate and free memory manually (which you aren't doing here), and there's no good way to know how much to allocate.

Comment: `cin>>Vector[i];` doesn't do what you expect it to.

Comment: VLAs are not proper C++:  `char *Vector[NumString];`

Comment: This is not array of strings, it's array of pointers to char

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`char *Vector[NumString]` is defined as an array of char pointers.
More on this:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7042/How-to-interpret-complex-C-C-declarations

Since none of the `char*` elements are initialized, your program is making an illegal memory access when attempting `cin` and gets closed/crashes.

To avoid this, you can use `std::string` instead which takes care of memory allocation for you.

Edit:
If you must use char arrays, you can do the following:
you can pre-allocate the `char` array lengths like so: `char Vector[numString][noteLength]`. Then use `std::cin >> std::setw(noteLength) >> Vector[i]`.

You could also dynamically allocate the pointers using your previous definition of `char *Vector[NumString]` and calling `Vector[i] = new char[noteLength]`. Don't forget to call `delete Vector[i]` when you're done!

You'd also have to `#include <iomanip>` to use `std::setw`

Comment: ok thank you so much for the article. Unfortunately i cannot use string but only pointers.

Comment: with the first solution the swap of the words works only fot the first character. With the second the compiler shows the same error

Comment: can you show what exactly the code looks like in the case you describe?